# How do I confirm a javascript prompt in Cypress?

Tags: testing, cypress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpkh5.png)

**
After I click on a button, this confirm window appears, but I didn't find anything that confirms this prompt**

**Part of the code that opens the prompt:**

```
 cy.get("iframe")
.its("0.contentDocument")
.its("body")
.find("#f_bln_assistencia_confirmar")
.click();
```